# How to remove the option to publish posts in the past with time stamp in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to customize wordpress for my needs and I manged to do allot of changes but I can't figure out this one by my self.

I don't want to allow to authors to set up time stamp for the past, I do want this option to be enabled but only for posting new posts in the feature. So the minimum required date is today so if they pick a date before today they will get a message or something and the post won't progress.

Does anyone have any Idea how can I accomplish this with plugin or maybe a filter ?

Thanks to everyone who helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post is what you need.

```
add_action('save_post', 'stop_publishing', 20);
function stop_publishing($post_id)
{
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    $post_date = $post->post_date;
    $current_date = date("Y-m-d");    

    //do your math of date calculation

    //user has set a date in the past, I am using an imaginary variable date_is_not_valid
    if ( $date_is_not_valid ) {
        $message = '<p>Please enter current or future date.</p>'
        . '<p><a href="' . admin_url('post.php?post=' . $post_id . '&action=edit') . '">Edit post</a></p>';
        wp_die($message, 'Error - Incorrect Date!');
    }   

}
```

Comment: Nice one, I don't know why I didn't think just to add action the save_post. Thank you very much !